# Use consistent wording for the date-based hats on the WB2020 homepage

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, winter-bash, wording, winter-bash-2020

If I visit the Winter Bash 2020 homepage, I can see the descriptions of the Bûche de Noël and Where in the World (Sun/Moon)? hats:

> **Bûche de Noël**
> Ask, answer, or vote on December 25th

> **Where in the World (Moon)?**
> Post or vote on Dec 21
>
> **Where in the World (Sun)?**
> Post or vote on Dec 21

[image: screenshot of the hats showing the different wording]

Can you please use consistent wording for these two (three) hats? Expanded, they all say "Ask, answer, or vote", but they should either all say "Ask, answer, or vote" on the short description or they should all say "Post or vote".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Date-based hats now have more consistent wording, per your suggestion.

> Should we just say "post"?
> Or "Ask, answer" more complete?
> Nitpick, amirite?